# Leer de SOAP un xsi:type en Java 1.8

Tags: java, xml, soap, maven

Estoy accediendo a un WSDL en mi aplicacion Java y al ejecutar el SOAP veo que recupera los siguientes atributos:

```
<listaConceptoEconomico xsi:type="_130:tronDdoConConceptoEcoS">
                  <codeco>8</codeco>
                  <impeco>0.09</impeco>
                  <ext/>
               </listaConceptoEconomico>
               <listaRecibos xsi:type="_130:tronDdoConRecibosS">
                  <numrecibo>8147150057</numrecibo>
                  <conceptoseco>
                     <array>
                        <codeco>17</codeco>
                        <impeco>-17.36</impeco>
                        <nomeco>DESCUENTO COMERCIAL</nomeco>
                        <ext/>
                     </array>
...
```

Cuando en mi clase Java declaro el Objeto que guardar los datos del SOAP para cargarlos en pantalla mediante el metodo getListaConceptoEconomico (metodo que se ha creado desde el WSDL me devuelve un null. Creo que es por xsi:type ya que los demas atributos del WSDL no lo tiene y me cargan sus valores perfectamente ¿Que codigo deberia poner para recuperarlos?

Incluyo codigo que tengo ahora:

```
Node IDENIMPORTES = XMLUtilidades.aniadeNuevoElemento(padre, nombre);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        try {
            PlanPagoBO[] listaPlanPago=  polizaSptoCanal.getObtenerPolizaSptoCanalResponse().getMssObtenerPolizaSptoCanal().getListaPlanPagoArray();
            for(PlanPagoBO datoPlanPago : listaPlanPago) {
                Element hijoIDENIMPORTES = XMLUtilidades.aniadeNuevoElemento(IDENIMPORTES, "REGISTRO");

                double ips = 0;
                ConceptoEconomicoBO[] listaConceptosEconomicos = datoPlanPago.getListaConceptoEconomicoArray();

                for(ConceptoEconomicoBO datoConcepto : listaConceptosEconomicos) {
                    String nombreConcepto = datoConcepto.toString();
                    String codigoConcepto = datoConcepto.getConceptoEconomico();
                    if(codigoConcepto == "11") {
                        ips = datoConcepto.getImporteConceptoEconomico();
                    }
                }

                ReciboBO[] listaDatosRecibos = datoPlanPago.getListaRecibosArray();
                for(ReciboBO datoReciboP : listaDatosRecibos) {
                    String numeroReciboO = datoReciboP.getRecibo();
                    System.out.println(numeroReciboO);
                }


                ReciboBO datoRecibo = datoPlanPago.getListaRecibosArray(0);
                String numeroRecibo = datoRecibo.getRecibo();
                ConceptoEconomicoBO[] listaConceptosEconomicos2 = datoRecibo.getListaConceptoEconomicoArray();
                for(ConceptoEconomicoBO conceptoseco : listaConceptosEconomicos2) {
                    String codeco = conceptoseco.getConceptoEconomico();
                    double impeco = conceptoseco.getImporteConceptoEconomico();
                    String strImporte = String.valueOf(df.format(impeco));
                    XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "PRIMANETATOTAL", "");
                    XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "IMPUESTOSTOTAL", "");
                    double primaTotal =  datoPlanPago.getImportePrimaTotal();
                    String strprimaTotal = String.valueOf(df.format(primaTotal));
                    XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "PRIMATOTAL", strprimaTotal);
                    XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "PRIMANETARECIBO", "");
                    XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "IMPUESTOSRECIBO", "");
                    switch(codeco) {
                    case "6":
                        XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "PRIMATOTALRECIBO", strImporte);
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "CLEA", strImporte);
                        break;
                    case "50":
                        XMLUtilidades.aniadeAtributo(hijoIDENIMPORTES, "FRACCIONAMIENTO", strImporte);
                        break;
                    }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola. Incluye el código Java con el que intentas procesar este mensaje.

Comment: Edito añadiendo código